# JQuery Slider Control - slider-handle not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, slider

I've got a text scrollbox made with JQuery.  It works fine when on its own (nationalboston.com/temp) but when I hand it off to be wrapped into a Joomla page, the slider handle doesn't move ([here](http://www.nationalboston.com/staging/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=112&Itemid=28)).  As far as I can tell, everything else works fine.

I've inspected the computed CSS in Chrome Inspector, and it seems that the handle is styled as it should be (position:absolute; top:auto;).  What am I doing wrong?!

EDIT:This appears to be the case in Safari 3.x Mac and Chrome 3 Alpha Mac,  Not in Firefox Mac.  I haven't done further testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed your link in Firefox 3.0.11 on mac and the slider works perfectly. Did you find the solution to your problem? The first idea that came to me when I read your question was that you might have a javascript namespace conflict (using more than one JS framework?). A possible solution would then have been to run JQuery in no-conflict mode, as in:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
jQuery("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

More info there: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict

Comment: Just checked it in FF -- it does work fine.  Unfortunately it doesn't work correctly in Safari Mac or Chrome Mac.

Comment: Alright, after a bit of digging it looks like this may be a conflict between mootools (used by Joomla) and JQuery...  I'll try using noConflict mode.